# Spark Streaming Set of Data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

I am relatively new to Databricks and am  trying to and read incoming sensor data and fire a ruleset based in each set of data. Looking for some help and guidance on how to proceed further

```
val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder("ConnectionString")   
    .setEventHubName("EventHubname")
    .build

  val eventHubsConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
    .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)
    .setConsumerGroup("azuredatabricks")

  val eventhubs = spark.readStream
    .format("eventhubs")
    .options(eventHubsConf.toMap)
    .load() 

 /*
  val df = eventhubs.select(($"enqueuedTime").as("Enqueued_Time"),($"systemProperties.iothub- 
           connection-device-id") .as("Device_ID"),($"body".cast("string")).as("telemetry_json")) 

  df.createOrReplaceTempView("tel_table")
*/
```

The code above reads incoming streaming data from EventHub and loads the data in dataframe as well ( commented section of code). Now I need  to loop through each row of data and pass it to ruleset. Since its a streaming data,spark sql throws error. Could somebody guide on how these streaming data can be read sequentially.

The next part on which I was looking for help is on how to infer schema from body of messages. Since these are sensor data so the schema won't be static. One message can have DeviceId,Temperature,pH and other would be Device,Voltage,Current. For cases like these is there a way to infer the schema dynamically in Apache Spark.

Thanks a lot for help in advance.

Comment: just to clarify, it is the commented out code that gives you the error right?

Comment: It loads in dataframe and when a select on table  tel_table" is done it throws an error “Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream..".  Was looking on guidance on what is the correct way of looping through records in dataframe for streaming data.

Comment: I suggest to read corresponding chapter from "Learning Spark, 2ed": https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly - it's free